# Extending models with additional fields in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to figure out a way to extend a model in Doctrine. I have the following situation

Card Model (The base model):

```
Nos\CardBundle\Entity\Card:
    type: entity
    table: cards
    inheritanceType: SINGLE_TABLE
    discriminatorColumn:
        name: card_type
        type: string
    discriminatorMap:
        staff: Nos\StaffBundle\Entity\Staff
        supplier: Nos\SupplierBundle\Entity\Supplier
    id:
        id:
            id: true
            type: integer
            length: 11
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
            options:
                unsigned: true
    fields:
        user_id:
            type: integer
            length: 11
            nullable: true
            options:
                unsigned: true
        card_display_name:
            type: string
            length: 255
            nullable: false
```

I discriminate the model using the card_type property. When it's 'staff', it should return a Staff model, when it's 'supplier' it should return a Supplier Model

Staff Model (Extends Card model)

```
Nos\StaffBundle\Entity\Staff:
    type: entity
    inheritance:
        extends: Nos\CardBundle\Entity\Card
        type: simple
    staff_initials:
        type: string
        length: 15
    staff_baptismal_names:
        type: string
        length: 255
```

and the Supplier model

```
Nos\StaffBundle\Entity\Supplier:
    type: entity
    inheritance:
        extends: Nos\CardBundle\Entity\Card
        type: simple
    supplier_name:
        type: string
        length: 255
```

When I generate the tables, the additional fields in Supplier and Staff models are not being created. Do I have to define those additional fields in the Card model? And if so, how can I exclude them from the models that they don't belong to?

Comment: You're not using the `fields` key in your mapping also I'm pretty sure you don't need the `inheritance` parts for your extending models.

Comment: You are using `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance so only one table is created with all the fields. Are the *"additional fields* created in `cards` table ?

Comment: I think for some reason, the YAML configuration doesn't work right with inheritance. I managed to fix it using Annotations, but I am still curious for a yaml solution.